# Libraries Load in One File but Not Another

Tags: r

I installed R Studio a month ago, along with a bunch of packages. I've been using `library(tidyverse)` for 3 weeks, and all of a sudden it isn't loading in my new project. Nor is the rMarkdown or any libraries I downloaded previously. Yet, when I open a previous project with `library(tidyverse)`, it will let me use the package. What should I do?

I haven't updated the software, yet.

Comment: Check `R.version`. In your current directory, look for the presence of a `.Rprofile` file that might be calling (e.g.) `renv`-functions or setting `.libpaths()`. Check the value of `.libPaths()` in general to see where R thinks it should be looking for packages (in both dirs).

Comment: When you say it isn't loading, does that mean you are getting an error? If so, what exactly is the error? Do you use `renv` at all?

Comment: It just went away but it was saying that I would have to download the packages. Then when i tried to use install.package I kept hitting an error.  I'll try r2Evan's response.

Comment: Here's the error: Error in if (cond) return(expr) : the condition has length > 1
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(R(), args, stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) :
  running command ''/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/bin/R' CMD config CC 2>&1' had status 1

Comment: I don't understand that error. What is the expression you evaluated to get that error? (I don't use RStudio, so if it's specific to their internal code then I'm not aware.)

Comment: Would be helpful to know the context of that error. Could you please provide a screenshot which shows where you are seeing it?